# Why does moving an async callback outside of a loop change the result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Consider the following code snippets:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var newObject = new someFunction(arr[i]);
    //async callback function
    $http.get('someurl').then(
        function(data) {
            newObject.data = data;
        }
    );
}
```

VS

```
function registerCallbacks(o) {
    $http.get('someurl').then(
        function(data) {
            o.data = data;
        }
    );
}

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var newObject = new someFunction(arr[i]);
    registerCallbacks(newObject);
}
```

The first example will perform the async operation only on the last object in the array, while the second example will work as expected.
I understand that in the first example, the callbacks all refer to the same variable 'newObject', so only one object is acted upon.
But why isn't it like this in the second example as well? Wouldn't 'o' end up referring to the parameter of the last function call?

I'm afraid I've missed something fundamental about how values are passed in javascript and would be grateful if someone could elucidate me on how it works.

Cheers!

Comment: There's a new `o` for every invocation of `registerCallbacks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `newObject` object may not have the same value by the time asynch callBack is invoked since its scope is still there in its parent method, and the prevailing values of `newObject` will be used by the inner block.

However, in the second one `newObject` is passed to another method as `o` (a new reference) which doesn't have the same variables in scope since it is outside that for loop block.

Comment: I think I understand. Would it be fair to say that the reason it works is that each function call results in a distinct scope, whereas each iteration of a loop takes place within the same scope?

Comment: @JonathanQuinth yes and the scope is related to the block in which you are present. In the first set, callback is in same block as for loop while in second the block is different.